# How can I start in command mode (not insert mode) in readline's vi editting-mode

Tags: shell, vi, readline, command-line-interface

Full question in title

Use case:

At a shell prompt, I hit return. I want to go up to the previous line, so I hit `<esc>k`. I'd rather not have to `<esc>` that command.

Seems to me that `i` is only a command, and should not be the default mode. As it is not in vi, nor vim, nor neo

Comment: If you want `k` instead of `<esc>k` to go up, how could the shell tell that `k` isn't the first character of the next command you want to type, say `kill`?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the [readline user manual](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html) -- you might have to resort to patching the source and rebuilding.

Comment: @Jens - k could not be the first letter of kill because I haven't entered insert mode yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer is to map an disposable key to the right vi-mode commands. For example I have added to [my ~/.inputrc](https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/blob/master/etc/inputrc) just such [a mapping for the # key](https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/commit/7c2cf0057eb01484fd89929202932c9f9f50573a).

Working on variants for , ...